# Can I travel to the US on a F1 visa to attend a funeral?

Tags: air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, f1-visas

I have a valid F1 visa and I want to travel to the US for 2 weeks. My intent is not to study but to visit my best friend who recently lost her boyfriend and to attend his funeral. I read that it takes up to 72 hours to get the application for an ESTA accepted and I need to travel before the 72 hours. So my question is can I travel on the F1 visa that expires in a year (I graduated from the USA last summer) or do I need the ESTA? Do I apply for the ESTA even though it may not be approved in time? I am from the UK.

Comment: Since you completed the program (graduated) and exited the country, are you certain that your F-1 is valid for re-entry? The F-1 covers only the time you are fully-registered as a student.

Comment: Despite the "up to", in the majority of cases an ESTA application is accepted instantly.  I would suggest that instead of worrying, you go and complete the application right now; if it's accepted, which is very likely, your question will be moot.

Comment: @pnuts If you answer all the questions the "right" way and your passport isn't flagged, it'll automatically approve your registration. Only if the system freezes the application would an officer have to Review it

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you need the ESTA.

Traveling for a funeral is not a valid purpose for an F1 student visa.

Comment: @pnuts No, it's a _student_ visa. Entering on it requires that you be attending an educational instutition, and _also_ be carrying paperwork (the I-20 form) to that effect. If you've graduated and aren't going back for further studies, then it's of no use.

Comment: Can confirm, OP definitely Needs an ESTA, and should apply for entry in WT status

Comment: For completeness sake, could you please link to the official regulations?

Answer (score 3):

ESTA is needed.

In order to prevent F1 visa usage [for reasons unrelated to the study](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/study-exchange/student.html), F1 visa must be accompanied by a proper visa document (I-20) and valid, current [SEVIS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student_and_Exchange_Visitor_Program) (created by your school designated official, maintained by the CBP/ICE). Since you have graduated, your I-20 is invalid, and your electronic record in SEVIS has been terminated.